# PHP FPM do not display errors

Tags: php, nginx, error-handling, error-reporting, fpm

**php5.6-fpm on ubuntu**

**/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini**

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

**/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

Anyway, errors displayed in nginx error log, not in browser output.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/4198099

Comment: Check your php_info() and the path to the ini file

Answer (score 0):

It was Symfony framework's kernel environment redefining configuration:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Changing it to true solved an issue.